# Рандомное изменение стейта

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не получается выбрать рандомный элемент в `this.state.cards` и поменять его состояние:

```js
    this.state = {
      cards: [
        {
          id: 1,
          active: 0
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          active: 0
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          active: 0
        }
      ]
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
      let randomElem = Math.round(Math.random() * 2); //рандомлю число от 0 до 2
      let randomCard = this.state.cards[randomElem].active; //подставляю зарандомленное число 
    
      this.setState({
        randomCard: 1 //пытаюсь изменить стейт в зарандомленном элементе массива
      })
      console.log(this.state)
    
 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

`this.state.active` как был 0, так и остается. Что я делаю не так?

**Рабочий вариант здесь** https://codepen.io/likeavenus/pen/jJQyQO?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас вы в функции `setState` создаете новое свойство в state `randomCard` и ему устанавливаете значение 1, переменная `randomCard` и свойство объекта `randomCard` - это разные вещи. Вам нужно сначала создать новый массив, в нём изменить рандомный элемент и уже потом указать его в качестве свойства `cards` в `state`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      cards: [
        {
          id: 1,
          active: 0
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          active: 0
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          active: 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount (){
    const randomElem = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
    const newCards = [...this.state.cards];
    newCards[randomElem].active = 1;
    
    this.setState({
      cards: newCards
    });
    
    console.log(this.state);
    
  }  

  render() {
    return <i>text</i>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: понял свою ошибку, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Думаю логика понятна.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        active: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        active: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        active: 2,
      },
    ],
    random: null,
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.setState({ random: this.state.data[Math.round(Math.random() * 2)].active });
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log(this.state.random);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Some text</h1>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: спасибо что потратили время и ответили, но что в моем коде не так?

Comment: @RafaelShepard, где у Вас состояние `randomCard`?

Comment: я понял ошибку, спасибо!